# How to copy over a user group from one domain to another?

Tags: windows, vbscript, batch-file, cmd, usergroups

So basically, I have a group say "Prod" on the production domain. I wanna copy over this group to my test domain and retain the users and the privileges.

How can I do this? Is there a way to do it using `BATCH` or `VBscript`?

I tried `net group`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`net group` doesn't work cross-domain. You could try [`ldifde`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237677) to export in the source domain and re-import it in the destination domain. [ADMT v3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17488) for environments using Windows NT 4.0 up to Windows 2003, or [ADMT v3.2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8377) for Windows 2000 to 2008 R2 environments may be another option.

Are the two domains in the same forest (or, more specifically, does a trust exist between them)? Otherwise you'll have to migrate not only the group, but also the users (can be handled by ADMT as well).

Comment: Yes, they are both in the same forest. Ok, I'll be trying ADMT v3.2 since all are servers are win 2003 and above.